# Convert *const __CFData to String in Rust

Tags: objective-c, macos, rust, core-foundation

I am trying to convert `*const __CFData` to `String` in rust.

I am trying to get Keyboard language and checking if it is a particular language.

```
let current_source = ffi::TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource();
let current_language = ffi::TISGetInputSourceProperty(current_source, ffi::kTISPropertyLocalizedName);
let language = CFDataGetBytePtr(current_language);
CStr::from_ptr(language).to_str().unwrap().to_string().contains("English")
```

I get this runtime error - `-[__NSCFConstantString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff85dfed1d8`

`TISGetInputSourceProperty` returns a `*const __CFData` and `CFDataGetBytePtr` should return a `*const u8`, but it fails at that function with the mentioned error.

How do I get the language and check what it is in rust?
TIA.

Comment: I don't think that this is a C string. Try using `CFDataGetLength` to get the length of the string, then you can use that information with to create a temporary `&[u8]` with [`from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html#) which can be converted to a string for your check.

Comment: "`TISGetInputSourceProperty` returns a `*const __CFData`" — actually, `TISGetInputSourceProperty` returns a `void *` in C, with the effective underlying return type being determined by the property you're trying to get. `kTISPropertyLocalizedName` is documented to return a `CFStringRef`, _not_ a `CFData`, which is why `CFDataGetBytePtr` fails. Try using [`CFStringRefGetCStringPtr`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542133-cfstringgetcstringptr) on `current_language` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with this a little, and came up with the following, which *seems* to work. Note that, as far as I could tell, this API is definitely deprecated though.

(the following needs `libc` as a dependency)

```rust
use libc::{size_t, c_void, c_char};

// A lot of these types taken from https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs/blob/0876315e2e434c2b5e5f406e7d540360c24b8c2e/core-foundation-sys/src/base.rs#L24
pub type CFStringEncoding = u32;
pub type Boolean = u8;
pub type CFIndex = isize;
pub static kCFStringEncodingUTF8: CFStringEncoding = 0x08000100;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct __CFString(c_void);
pub type CFStringRef = *const __CFString;

#[link(name = "Carbon", kind = "framework")]
extern "C" {
    fn TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource() -> *const c_void;
    fn TISGetInputSourceProperty(a: *const c_void, b: *const c_void) -> CFStringRef;
    static kTISPropertyLocalizedName: *const c_void;
}

#[link(name = "CoreFoundation", kind = "framework")]
extern {
    pub fn CFStringGetCString(theString: CFStringRef,
        buffer: *mut c_char,
        bufferSize: CFIndex,
        encoding: CFStringEncoding)
        -> Boolean;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let v = vec![0; 256];
        let s = std::ffi::CString::from_vec_unchecked(v);
        let ptr = s.into_raw();

        let source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
        let y = TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyLocalizedName);
        CFStringGetCString(y, ptr, 256, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

        println!("{:?}", std::ffi::CString::from_raw(ptr));
        // Prints "ABC" on my machine
    }
}
```

Note that `CFStringGetCStringPtr` did not work for me, as it returned a null-pointer. I'm guessing this is because ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542133-cfstringgetcstringptr)):

> [Returns] NULL if the internal storage of theString does not allow [the pointer] to be returned efficiently.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I figured that in documentation the type returned by `TISGetInputSourceProperty` is `CTypeRef`. So I was able to return `CTypeRef` and convert it into `CFStringRef` and also any other type that it might return depending on the property.

Comment: I do not see it being deprecated. I was able to use Xcode and view the documentation. It was not mentioned as deprecated in the `Carbon.HIToolBox.TextInputSources` and I am using latest. Can you tell me where you see it deprecated?

Comment: As far as I understand [Carbon was deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API)#Deprecation%20and%20discontinuation) in its entirety in 2021.

Comment: In that case, is there any other way to identify keyboard layout?

Comment: Looks like not all functionalities are deprecated, some are still available to use. The official website states `In macOS 10.8 and later, *most* of these APIs are deprecated. `. Deprecated ones are marked as `*Deprecated*` in the documentation.